# phpmyadmin JavaScript fatal error when trying to save a page with a diagram

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

I have the following `fatal JavaScript error` when I try to save a page with an ER diagram in `phpmyadmin`. The operating system is `MacOS Sierra` and the following code is when I use `Safari`.

```
{
        "pma_version": "4.6.4",
        "browser_name": "SAFARI",
        "browser_version": "10.0.1",
        "user_os": "Mac",
        "server_software": "Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) PHP/5.6.25",
        "user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/602.2.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.1 Safari/602.2.11",
        "locale": "en",
        "configuration_storage": "disabled",
        "php_version": "5.6.25",
        "exception_type": "js",
        "exception": {
            "mode": "stack",
            "name": "DataError",
            "message": "Failed to store record in an IDBObjectStore: Evaluating the object store's key path yielded a value that is not a valid key.",
            "stack": [
                {
                    "line": 235,
                    "func": "",
                    "context": [
                        "                lastException = null;",
                        "                notifyHandlers.apply(null, [stack, null].concat(args));",
                        "            }",
                        "        }, (stack.incomplete ? 2000 : 0));",
                        "",
                        "        throw ex; // re-throw to propagate to the top level (and cause wind//...",
                        "    }",
                        "",
                        "    report.subscribe = subscribe;",
                        "    report.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;",
                        "    return report;"
                    ],
                    "filename": "tracekit/tracekit.js"
                },
                {
                    "func": "addObject",
                    "args": "",
                    "line": 104,
                    "column": "35",
                    "context": [
                        "",
                        "    designerDB.addObject = function(table, obj, callback) {",
                        "        var db = datastore;",
                        "        var transaction = db.transaction([table], 'readwrite');",
                        "        var objStore = transaction.objectStore(table);",
                        "        var request = objStore.put(obj);",
                        "",
                        "        request.onsuccess = function(e) {",
                        "            if (typeof callback !== 'undefined' && callback !== null) {",
                        "                callback(e.currentTarget.result);",
                        "            }"
                    ],
                    "filename": "pmd/designer_db.js"
                },
                {
                    "func": "Create_new_page",
                    "args": "",
                    "line": 49,
                    "column": "32",
                    "context": [
                        "}",
                        "",
                        "function Create_new_page(db, page_name, callback)",
                        "{",
                        "    var newPage = new PDFPage(db, page_name);",
                        "    DesignerOfflineDB.addObject('pdf_pages', newPage, function (pg_nr) {",
                        "        newPage.pg_nr = pg_nr;",
                        "        if (typeof callback !== 'undefined') {",
                        "            callback(newPage);",
                        "        }",
                        "    });"
                    ],
                    "filename": "pmd/designer_page.js"
                },
                {
                    "func": "Save_to_new_page",
                    "args": "",
                    "line": 15,
                    "column": "20",
                    "context": [
                        "    });",
                        "}",
                        "",
                        "function Save_to_new_page(db, page_name, table_positions, callback)",
                        "{",
                        "    Create_new_page(db, page_name, function (page) {",
                        "        if (page) {",
                        "            var tbl_cords = [];",
                        "            for (var pos = 0; pos < table_positions.length; pos++) {",
                        "                table_positions[pos].pdf_pg_nr = page.pg_nr;",
                        "                Save_table_positions(table_positions[pos], function (id) {"
                    ],
                    "filename": "pmd/designer_page.js"
                },
                {
                    "func": "click",
                    "args": "",
                    "line": 11,
                    "column": "3361",
                    "context": [
                        "(function(e){\"function\"==typeof define&&define.amd?define([\"jquery\"],e):e(j//...",
                        "},_clear:function(){this.helper.removeClass(\"ui-draggable-dragging\"),this.h//...",
                        "this.element.addClass(\"ui-selectable\"),this.dragged=!1,this.refresh=functio//...",
                        "},_refresh:function(){var t,i=this.options,s=i.heightStyle,n=this.element.p//...",
                        "},_destroyDatepicker:function(t){var i,s=e(t),n=e.data(t,\"datepicker\");s.ha//...",
                        "return this._isOpen?(this._moveToTop()&&this._focusTabbable(),void 0):(this//...",
                        "},_keydown:function(t){var i=this.options,s=e.ui.keyCode;switch(t.keyCode){//...",
                        "return t.parent().is(\".ui-effects-wrapper\")&&(t.parent().replaceWith(t),(t[//...",
                        "",
                        "/*jslint browser: true */ /*global jQuery: true */",
                        ""
                    ],
                    "filename": "jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"
                },
                {
                    "func": "new_func",
                    "args": "",
                    "line": 249,
                    "column": "38",
                    "context": [
                        "     */",
                        "    wrap_function: function (func) {",
                        "        if (!func.wrapped) {",
                        "            var new_func = function () {",
                        "                try {",
                        "                    return func.apply(this, arguments);",
                        "                } catch (x) {",
                        "                    TraceKit.report(x);",
                        "                }",
                        "            };",
                        "            new_func.wrapped = true;"
                    ],
                    "filename": "error_report.js"
                },
                {
                    "func": "dispatch",
                    "args": "",
                    "line": 3,
                    "column": "6471",
                    "context": [
                        "/*! jQuery v2.1.4 | (c) 2005, 2015 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/lic//...",
                        "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                        "return M.access(a,b,c)},removeData:function(a,b){M.remove(a,b)},_data:funct//...",
                        "void 0===c?d&&\"get\"in d&&null!==(e=d.get(a,b))?e:(e=n.find.attr(a,b),null==//...",
                        ";",
                        "",
                        "function sprintf() {",
                        "/*"
                    ],
                    "filename": "jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
                },
                {
                    "func": "dispatch",
                    "args": "",
                    "line": 374,
                    "column": "24",
                    "context": [
                        "$event.dispatch = function( event ){",
                        "\tif ( $.data( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type ) - new Date().getTime() > 0 ){",
                        "\t\t$.removeData( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type );",
                        "\t\treturn;",
                        "\t}",
                        "\treturn $dispatch.apply( this, arguments );",
                        "};",
                        "",
                        "// event fix hooks for touch events...",
                        "var touchHooks = ",
                        "$event.fixHooks.touchstart = "
                    ],
                    "filename": "jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
                },
                {
                    "func": "handle",
                    "args": "",
                    "line": 3,
                    "column": "3246",
                    "context": [
                        "/*! jQuery v2.1.4 | (c) 2005, 2015 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/lic//...",
                        "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                        "return M.access(a,b,c)},removeData:function(a,b){M.remove(a,b)},_data:funct//...",
                        "void 0===c?d&&\"get\"in d&&null!==(e=d.get(a,b))?e:(e=n.find.attr(a,b),null==//...",
                        ";",
                        "",
                        "function sprintf() {",
                        "/*"
                    ],
                    "filename": "jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
                }
            ],
            "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/602.2.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.1 Safari/602.2.11",
            "incomplete": "false",
            "partial": "true",
            "uri": "db_designer.php?"
        },
        "script_name": "db_designer.php",
        "microhistory": null
    }
```

I have tried both Firefox and Chrome, but I still get the same error message.